# Change child of certain parents with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, if-statement, parent

1U have a file directory with multiple files. I need to change the mime-type-icons of some files, as the default ones aren't specifically enough. I also have to insert the code via jquery, because I cannot change the mimetype-function.

My HTML looks like this:

```html
<tr data-file="filename.psd" data-mime="application/octet-stream">
  <td class="td_01">
    <a class="name">
      <div class="thumbnail" style="background-image:url(/img/filetypes/image.svg)"></div>
    </a>
  </td>
</tr>

<tr data-file="filename.sketch" data-mime="application/octet-stream">
  <td class="td_01">
    <a class="name">
      <div class="thumbnail" style="background-image:url(/img/filetypes/image.svg)"></div>
    </a>
  </td>
</tr>
```

As you see, the thumbnail of my photoshop-file and of my sketch-file are the same.

Now, I want to change the 'style' attribute of the child div related to the file-extension. If the extension of the data-file-attribute is .psd > then change div#thumbnail's style-attribute to .../filetypes/psd.svg. 
If data-file-attribute is .sketch > div#thumbnails's stle-attribute should be .../filetypes/sketch.svg. And so on...

How can this be done? Any ideas? I am new to jQuery.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Just loop over them, and then filter by `.thumbnail`:

```
$('tr[data-file]').each(function() {  
    let extension = $(this).data('file').split('.').pop().toLowerCase();
    $(this).find('.thumbnail').css('background-image', 'url(/img/filetypes/'+extension+'.svg)');
});
```

Comment: But then it would also change thumbnail-icons for JPGs and PNGs. However, they should remain image.svg. Sorry - didn’t mention that!